# Nested Beautiful Soup classes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch all classes (including the data inside "data_from", "data_to") from the following structure:

```
<div class="alldata">
  <div class="data_from">
  <div class="data_to">
  <div class="data_to">
  <div class="data_from">
</div>
```

So far I have tried finding all classes, without success. The "data_from", "data_to" classes are not being fetched by:

```
soup.find_all(class_=True)
```

When I try to illiterate over "alldata" class I fetch only the first "data_from" class.

```
for data in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "alldata"}):
    print(data.prettify())
```

All assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` or a mix with new syntax - instead use `find_all()` only - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

Your HTML is not valid, but to get your goal with valid HTML you could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that selects all `<div>` with a class that are contained in your outer `<div>`:

```
soup.select('.alldata div[class]')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div class="alldata">
  <div class="data_from"></div>
  <div class="data_to"></div>
  <div class="data_to"></div>
  <div class="data_from"></div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('.alldata div[class]')
```

###### Output

```
[<div class="data_from"></div>,
 <div class="data_to"></div>,
 <div class="data_to"></div>,
 <div class="data_from"></div>]
```

---

Just in addition if you like to get its texts, iterate over your `ResultSet`:

```
for e in soup.select('.alldata div[class]'):
    print(e.text)
```